# How to integrate django-admin-bootstrapped with django 1.10

Tags: django-1.10

How can I use django-admin-bootstrapped with django 1.10.

https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped

I used to be able to install admin-bootstratpped_plus and django-admin-bootstrapped but it no longer works since it does not support django 1.10

Any idea?

Comment: what is bootstrap-admin?

Comment: It is for the django admin interface to look similar to twitter. https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped

Answer (score 1):

I've also had the same problem since migrating to django 1.10. Waiting for newer version of django-admin-bootstrapped may take time. Instead of waiting and using the package install from pip I use manual mode installation.

See if django-admin-bootstrapped already existed on your environment:

```
$ pip list
Django (1.10.6)
django-admin-bootstrapped (2.5.7)
```

Uninstall it:

```
$ pip uninstall django-admin-bootstrapped
```

Clone or download django-admin-bootstrapped source from its repository https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped.

Edit setup.py:

```
install_requires=[
        'setuptools',
        'Django>=1.8', # previously 'Django>=1.8,<1.9',
],
```

Then install it manually:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Now the "new" django-admin-bootstrapped 2.5.7 can be used for django 1.10

Check it out:

```
$ pip list
django-admin-bootstrapped (2.5.7)
```

Don't forget to edit your settings.py:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_admin_bootstrapped', # Add this before django.contrib.admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
]`

Run migrate, then run your django app and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, see it's bootstrapped now.